# Reflection: How to create a Class[] with method parameter of double[]

Tags: java, unit-testing, reflection

I have a method:

```
 static double sum(double[] out, int numberVerticies) {}
```

I am trying to unit test it using reflection. I keep getting NoSuchMethodException.

I think it is because the args I am passing in are not matching the method.

here is my test method:

```
 @Test
void sum(){
    double[] out ={1,2,3,4};
    int numberVerticies = 4;
    Class[] args = new Class[]{Array.class,Integer.TYPE};
    Object[] params = new Object[]{out,numberVerticies};

    try {
        Method sum = reflectClass.getDeclaredMethod("sum", args);
        sum.setAccessible(true);


        double returnValue = (double) sum.invoke(pageRank,params);

    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I think it is this line that is causing the problem:

```
        Class[] args = new Class[]{Array.class,Integer.TYPE};
```

What type or class is a double[].

Comment: Thanks. double[].class works.

Comment: Note that for far more than a decade now, you can simply write `Method sum = reflectClass.getDeclaredMethod("sum", double[].class, int.class);` and `sum.invoke(pageRank, out, numberVerticies)`, and since Java 7, you can write `catch(NoSuchMethodException|IllegalAccessException|InvocationTargetException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }`, though in this case, you could also simply write `catch(ReflectiveOperationException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }`…